# C# Linq expression in C++

Tags: c++, linq

I am thinking to create a Linq library in C++ to do things like `theVector.select( ... )`, `theVector.where(...)`.
I am wondering if there is a way to extend a C++ class that have already been declared ( like `std::vector` ) I would like to be able to do :

```
theVector.select(...)
```

instead of

```
myClass( theVector ).select(...)
```

Is there anyway way to accomplish this [like in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981895.aspx) ?

Thanks,

Comment: There are multiple implementations of C++ LINQ out there.

Comment: @chris - can you post a (ahem) link to them?

Comment: @chris - Im doing it for fun

Comment: @Sean, For starters, there's [cpplinq](https://cpplinq.codeplex.com/). Most of what I've seen come up in articles have been structured similar to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ community seems to be moving towards non-member functions for this type of "utility thing not directly related to the class at hand". e.g. if you have a `std::vector v;` you could always `v.begin()`, but now you can also `std::begin(v)`. This would imply something like `select(theVector)...`.

But, you might want to support joins at some point, so I would consider

```
select(...).from(theVector).join(theMap, ...).where(...)
// or
select(...).from(theVector).order_by(...)
// etc.
```